# When I plot the markers in a trace with a symbol, it doesn't show up

Tags: python, plotly, symbols, marker, plotly-dash

I'm trying to generate a scattermapbox using dash and plotly, when I specify a symbol (e.g. "square") inside the marker, it doesn't render when the map is generated.
I'm using a callback function and I tried several symbols, none of which worked, but the circle marker.
Is there something obvious that I'm missing?
Here is a minimal example, to run it you will need a mapbox token.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import datetime as dt


app = dash.Dash()
mapbox_access_token = 'YOUR_MAPBOX_TOKEN_HERE'

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.H1('Dashboard'),
        dcc.DatePickerRange(id='fecha',
                            start_date=dt.datetime.today() - dt.timedelta(days=30),
                            end_date=dt.datetime.today()
                           ),
        html.Center(dcc.Graph(
            id='mapa',
            figure={
                'data': [
                    go.Scattermapbox(
                                    lat=[],
                                    lon=[],
                                )
                        ],
                'layout': go.Layout(
                                    autosize=False,
                                    width=1300,
                                    height=800,
                                    hovermode='closest',
                                    showlegend=False,
                                    mapbox=dict(
                                            accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
                                            bearing=0,
                                            center=dict(
                                                lat=-32,
                                                lon=-70
                                            ),
                                            pitch=0,
                                            zoom=5,
                                            ),
                                    )
                    })
        ,)
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('mapa', 'figure'),
     [dash.dependencies.Input('fecha', 'start_date'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('fecha', 'end_date')
    ])
def update_graph(inicio,fin):
    Data = [go.Scattermapbox(
                    name='square',
                    lat=[-31,-30],
                    lon=[-71,-71],
        marker = dict(
            symbol='square',
            size = 8,
            opacity = 0.8,
            color='grey'
            ),
            text = np.array(['square1','square2'])),
           go.Scattermapbox(
                    name='circle',
                    lat=[-31,-30],
                    lon=[-72,-72],
        marker = dict(
            symbol='circle',
            size = 8,
            opacity = 0.8,
            color='grey'
            ),
            text = ['circle1','circle2'])]

    figure={
            'data': Data,
            'layout': go.Layout(
            title='Visitas',
            autosize=False,
            width=1300,
            height=800,
            hovermode='closest',
            showlegend=True,
            mapbox=dict(
                accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
                bearing=0,
                center=dict(
                    lat=-30.5,
                    lon=-72
                ),
                pitch=0,
                zoom=5,
            ),
    )
    }
    return figure


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host= '0.0.0.0',port=9999)
```

I tried making the same mapbox without dash (i.e. just plotly), and it failed again, so it's not a dash problem, here is how I made the map with plotly (for this you'll need a plotly account):

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.plotly as py
mapbox_access_token = 'YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'
Data = [go.Scattermapbox(
                name='square',
                lat=[-31,-30],
                lon=[-71,-71],
    marker = dict(
        symbol='square',
        size = 8,
        opacity = 0.8,
        color='grey'
        ),
        text = ['square1','square2']),
       go.Scattermapbox(
                name='circle',
                lat=[-31,-30],
                lon=[-72,-72],
    marker = dict(
        symbol='circle',
        size = 8,
        opacity = 0.8,
        color='grey'
        ),
        text = ['circle1','circle2'])]

figure={
        'data': Data,
        'layout': go.Layout(
        title='Visitas',
        autosize=False,
        width=1300,
        height=800,
        hovermode='closest',
        showlegend=True,
        mapbox=dict(
            accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
            bearing=0,
            center=dict(
                lat=-30.5,
                lon=-72
            ),
            pitch=0,
            zoom=5,
        ),
)
}
py.iplot(figure, filename='Broken fig')
```

Thanks in advance, I still don't know if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: does it work with the plot alone? i.e. without dash?

Comment: good remark, I'll try and edit my question on monday

Comment: @MaximilianPeters It doesn't work without dash, I added the code for recreating the issue, I still have no clue why this happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the problem was mainly by 2 things:

- Mixing in the marker a symbol (square), with a default size and color (this feature is not supported).
- The symbol (square) is not supported by Scattermapbox, you can find a list here: [Supported Symbols!](https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-add-a-custom-symbol-image-inside-map/6641).

I also opened a github issue where you can find a bit more info [github issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/891)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am running into a similar issue. I have got the map on the page, however, no markers on the map. The data and layout objects seems fine, so I suspect it's something to do with the plotly/mapbox.